# SOLR 6.6: suggester with context filtering returns no result

Tags: solr, autosuggest

Previously, I had suggest configuration which worked with out context filtering:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
        <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_spell</str>
        <lst name="spellchecker">
            <str name="name">default</str>
            <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
            <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
            <str name="field">autosuggest_en</str>
            <str name="contextField">availableForWarehouses_string_mv</str>
            <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
            <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
            <str name="accuracy">0.35</str>
        </lst>
        <lst name="spellchecker">
            <str name="name">de</str>
            <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
            <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
            <str name="field">autosuggest_de</str>
            <str name="contextField">availableForWarehouses_string_mv</str>
            <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
            <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
            <str name="accuracy">0.35</str>
        </lst>
        <lst name="spellchecker">
            <str name="name">en</str>
            <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
            <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
            <str name="field">autosuggest_en</str>
            <str name="contextField">availableForWarehouses_string_mv</str>
            <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
            <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
            <str name="accuracy">0.35</str>
        </lst>
    </searchComponent>

    <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
        </lst>
        <arr name="components">
            <str>suggest</str>
        </arr>
    </requestHandler>
```

In solr admin console I was able to retrieve results:

[image]

Now, I have created configuration including context filtering:

```
<searchComponent name="hmmSuggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
        <lst name="suggester">
            <str name="name">default</str>
            <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
            <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
            <str name="field">autosuggest_en</str>
            <str name="contextField">availableForWarehouses_string_mv</str>
            <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
            <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
            <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
            <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
        </lst>
        <lst name="suggester">
            <str name="name">de</str>
            <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
            <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
            <str name="field">autosuggest_de</str>
            <str name="contextField">availableForWarehouses_string_mv</str>
            <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
            <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
            <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
            <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
        </lst>
        <lst name="suggester">
            <str name="name">en</str>
            <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
            <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
            <str name="field">autosuggest_en</str>
            <str name="contextField">availableForWarehouses_string_mv</str>
            <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
            <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
            <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
            <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
        </lst>
    </searchComponent>

    <requestHandler name="/hmmSuggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="suggest">true</str>
            <str name="suggest.count">5</str>
            <str name="suggest.dictionary">default</str>
            <str name="suggest.collate">true</str>
            <str name="suggest.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
        </lst>
        <arr name="components">
            <str>hmmSuggest</str>
        </arr>
    </requestHandler>
```

But I get no results.

[image]

Do I need to add something more to my configuration, or what could be an issue, or how can I check for an issue?

## Test 1

I tried to use class spellcheckcomponent instead of suggester, but I still get empty results.

```
<searchComponent name="hmmSuggest" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
        <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_spell</str>
        <lst name="spellchecker">
            <str name="name">default</str>
            <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
            <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
            <str name="field">autosuggest_en</str>
            <str name="contextField">availableForWarehouses_string_mv</str>
            <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
            <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
            <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
            <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
            <str name="accuracy">0.35</str>
        </lst>
        <lst name="spellchecker">
            <str name="name">de</str>
            <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
            <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
            <str name="field">autosuggest_de</str>
            <str name="contextField">availableForWarehouses_string_mv</str>
            <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
            <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
            <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
            <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
            <str name="accuracy">0.35</str>
        </lst>
        <lst name="spellchecker">
            <str name="name">en</str>
            <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
            <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
            <str name="field">autosuggest_en</str>
            <str name="contextField">availableForWarehouses_string_mv</str>
            <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
            <str name="buildOnStartup">true</str>
            <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
            <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
            <str name="accuracy">0.35</str>
        </lst>
    </searchComponent>

    <requestHandler name="/hmmSuggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
        </lst>
        <arr name="components">
            <str>hmmSuggest</str>
        </arr>
    </requestHandler>
```

Comment: But you have also switched from the SpellcheckSuggester to the SuggestComponent -- are you sure that context filtering is the actual issue here, and not the switch between those two ways of doing suggestions?

Comment: @MatsLindh I also don't get any results with SpellCheckComponent. Any suggestions ?

Comment: They use different configuration options. Move back to the one that works, then start replacing values one by one and see where it stops working as you expect. Don't change the whole config and then wonder what doesn't work as expected.